# Display all packets but not these TCP packets?

Tags: network, wireshark

I'm trying to filter packets with wireshark, I would like to display all packets but terminal service communications, but if I do:

`tcp.dstport != 3389 && tcp.srcport != 3389`

It would implicate `TCP` packets only, what should the syntax be like?

Comment: can you clarify what do you want to show and what you do not

Comment: A bit late to comment, but why are you asking this on a security site?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about IT security within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Whole `!=` thing doesn't work very well. If you notice your expression filter text area is yellow when you do that.

Try this instead.

```
!(tcp.dstport == 3389) && !(tcp.srcport == 3389)
```

I recommend reading the wireshark user guide. Section 6.4.4 specifically references the problem you had.

[User Guide -- Filter Section](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `tcp.port` to compress condition:

```
!tcp.port==3389
```

`tcp.port` means source port or destination port.